# Why do we distinguish between view and pure?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design

I understand that the difference is that, while neither may change the state, `view` may read the state and `pure` may not. I also understand that it's useful to distinguish possibly state-changing functions from those guaranteed not to change the state.

My question is, why is it useful to indicate that a function won't even access state? Why doesn't `view` suffice?

Comment: Probably in order to allow a higher level of compiler optimization for `pure` functions. And by the way, you could just as well ask the same question about `view` (i.e., why is it useful to indicate that a function won't change state?).

Comment: Oh, and another reason - it's there to protect you from doing things you didn't initially intend to. By declaring a `pure` function, you "remind" yourself (and others), that this function has no intention of reading state variables, nor to invoke any other function which reads state variables. It's kinda like `const` in C/C++. If you later decide to change functionality, you get this compilation error reminding you of your original design intentions.

Comment: Well the other question you propose - why is it useful to indicate a function won't change state - is both covered well elsewhere and more obvious: changing state costs money.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If a function is `pure`, then no matter how many times you call it, if you pass the same parameters, it will always return the same value(s).

Example:

```
function pureFunction(uint a) pure returns(uint){
    return a + 5;
}
```

will always return `6` if you pass `1` as parameter `a`.

However, if the function is `view`, it's reading from the state, which may have changed since the last time you called it.

Example:

```
uint B = 5;

function viewFunction(uint a) view returns(uint){
    return a + B;
}
```

will also return `6` if you pass `1` as parameter `a`. But if another function modifies the value of `B`, then next time you call `viewFunction(1)`, it will return something different.

Comment: I do not think that `pureFunction` example is a pure function

Answer (score -1):

I find the answer above confusing. It really boils down to this:

Pure does (can) not access state only memory/stack

View can access state but not make changes to it, just query (+ ETL).

No state changes in a transaction call means no gas cost, we're letting the compiler know that so we can get the right behaviour (sendTx vs call) after deployment.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The dude says he already knows the difference between `pure` and `view`.

Comment: And what's the common denominator? "no state modifications possible".